# Importance for Color in X ray imaging for Detection of Pneumonia

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, image-processing

I want to apply Deep learning architectures for detection of Pneumonia on chest X-rays, Should I directly apply CNN on RGB images or I should convert RGB into grayscale image and then apply CNN. Should not transforming RGB to grayscale lead to loss of important information of colours. Please help me in understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking classic X ray radiographs or some fancy modern technique ( MRI, PET-CT, Spectral-CT, ...). Classic X ray radiography has no color information. They measure how much of an electric charge was lost due to radiation and that is one dimensional. Earlier last century some chemistry was involved an silver made black and white images so clinicians still look at black and white images.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions are a type of hypercomplex numbers that can be used to represent rotations in 3D space, and quaternion neural networks (QNNs) have been proposed as a way to better model the non-linearities of 3D data. However, in the context of chest X-rays, which are 2D images, it's not clear that QNNs would provide any benefit over traditional CNN architectures.

Regarding your question about RGB versus grayscale images, the decision depends on the specific details of your problem. Grayscale images have only one channel (i.e., intensity) per pixel, while RGB images have three channels (red, green, and blue) per pixel. Converting RGB to grayscale will result in a loss of information about color, but it may simplify the model and make it easier to train.

In general, if color information is relevant to the problem at hand, then using RGB images may be better. For example, if the presence of certain colors is indicative of the presence or absence of pneumonia, then RGB images could help the model learn these relationships. However, if color is not relevant or the model is struggling to learn from the RGB images, then grayscale images may be a better choice.

It's important to note that in some cases, converting RGB to grayscale can introduce its own biases and distortions, so it's always a good idea to experiment with both approaches and evaluate the performance of the model on a held-out test set.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the RGB channels in an image store independent information -- for example, the amount of green light versus the amount of red light at a certain location.

Other times, we might choose to visualize some scalar field, like elevation or density, by converting scalar values into an RGB color, giving us an RGB image which is more pleasing to the eye. The mapping function is often called a "colormap".

Not being an expert on X-rays, I'm not sure which of these is the case here.

In the former case, converting from RGB to greyscale inevitably looses information, so it's probably not a great idea. In the latter case, you would likely also lose information because the mapping from your source data to greyscale image is probably not invertible. Yet neither do you want to use the RGB, since it contains redundant information and is 3 times the size. The better thing to do is use the source data before it was colormapped at all.

edit: Another case I forgot to mention -- sometimes, 1-channel data is mistakenly converted to a 3-channel format, where the values in each channel are duplicated. But you really only have 1 channel here.

Answer (score 0):

> transforming RGB to grayscale lead to loss of important information of colours

It would be easier to ask this to a radiologist instead of a statistician.

From the statistical point of view you try both and see which performs better.

However, whether or not the RGB channels have different (and important) information might already be answered based on theoretical considerations like 'how is the image created?'.

Another consideration: Images can sometimes have a slight hue instead of being completely black and white (like old sepia photo's), but possibly the light intensity captures all the information if this is just an artifact from the imaging. To test this you could create a plot of the colour as function of light intensity and see whether this creates a one dimensional scale (ie. only a single colour occurs at the same intensity and you get a single curve in the plot). In the case that your images are not completely black and white, and instead have a hue, then it might be useful to use all rgb channels because it is input with a higher precision. To have this work with a deep learning network you could convert the RGB to a single scale but with a function that is not simply taking the light intensity and instead uses the colour information as well.